# Accessing postgres data in docker-compose network

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm having trouble accessing a database created from a docker-compose file.

Given the following compose file, I should be able to connect to it from java using something like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://eprase:eprase@database:7000/eprase
```

However, the connection is rejected. I can't even use PGAdmin to connect it using the same details to create a new server.

I've entered the database container and ran psql commands to verify that the eprase user and database have been created according to postgres Docker documentation, everything seems fine. I can't tell if the problem is within the database container or something I need to change in the compose network.

The client & server services can largely be ignored, the server is a java based web API and the client is an Angular app.

Compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    image: eprase/client:latest
    build: ./client/eprase-app
    networks:
      api:
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - server
  server:
    image: eprase/server:latest
    build: ./server
    networks:
      api:
    ports:
      - "6000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    image: postgres:9
    volumes:
      - "./database/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=eprase"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=eprase"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=eprase"
    networks:
      api:
    ports:
      - "7000:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    environment: 
      - "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@eprase.com"
      - "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=eprase"
    networks:
      api:
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - database
networks:
  api:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PostgreSQL database is listening on container port `5432`. The `7000:5432` line is mapping host port `7000` to container port `5432`. That allows you to connect to the database on port 7000. But, your services on a common network (`api`) should communicate with each other via the container ports.

So, from the perspective of the containers for the client and server services, the connection string should be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://eprase:eprase@database:5432/eprase
```